# paste text to filenames in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have a list of strings in `String` that I want to add at the beginning of all files names of `Targets` in the folder. All files are ordered.

String.txt:

```
ID1Somestring_
IDISomeOtherString_
IDISomeThirdString_
```

Targets:

```
example1.fastq
example2.fastq
example3.fastq
```

output:

```
ID1Somestring_example1.fastq
IDISomeOtherString_example2.fastq
IDISomeThirdString_example3.fastq
```

Comment: cross site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227941/paste-files-without-delimiter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

Comment: @RedCricket How is that post a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

First, read the file into an array

```
mapfile -t strings < String.txt
```

Then, iterate over the files and access each array element in turn:

```
n=0; for file in *fastq; do echo mv "$file" "${strings[n++]}$file"; done
```

```
mv example1.fastq ID1Somestring_example1.fastq
mv example2.fastq IDISomeOtherString_example2.fastq
mv example3.fastq IDISomeThirdString_example3.fastq
```

---

Or, assuming your filenames do not contain newlines

```
paste String.txt <(printf "%s\n" *fastq) |
while read -r string file; do echo mv "$file" "$string$file"; done
```

Comment: That paste+while also assumes they don''t contain any white space. You could add `IFS=$'\t'` before the `read` and then it'd just rely on the first arg not containing any tabs which is a bit better (I personally come across file names with blanks every day but rarely if ever tabs or newlines).

Comment: spaces in the filename are not a problem. The first whitespace-separated field goes into "string" and the rest of the line goes into "file".

Comment: I was referring to the file name prefixes stored in String.txt containing spaces, that's what I mean by `the first arg` but I wasn't clear.